# Fluent API HasColumnType - Database Agnostic

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-interface

We are currently using the following to set money column types in MS SQL Server.

```
entity.Property(e => e.UnitPrice).HasColumnType("smallmoney");
```

or

```
entity.Property(e => e.UnitPrice).HasColumnType("money");
```

What, if at all, is a more database agnostic way?

Answer (score 0):

Use Decimal instead of Money.  Use Decimal in c# and in Db.
See also

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MetaDomain>().Property(d => d.xyz).HasPrecision(precision, scale);
```

[decimals in SQL server docu](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

[MSDN decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  which states

> which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

Surely Decimal is the most DB agnostic way of dealing with currency.
You should choose precision/scale to match the currencies and accuracy required.
And i would also suggest you always track the currency itself with the amount unless you know the solution never could or will apply beyond 1 currency.

For "monetary amounts" means catering 4 extra decimal places than the currency itself describes. Since industries like high volume retailers that manage items in fractions of cents. I had to demo 4 decimal places to a retailer in a presentation.
It means catering for many different currencies and as more organizations do in house treasury, if means catering for AT LEAST 5 decimals.  Im planning beyond that just in case.
[XDR special drawing rights](http://www.xe.com/currency/xdr-imf-special-drawing-rights)

Comment: Phil, I think the OP is looking for a way to map to the most appropriate datatype a database vendor displays without having to define a mapping for each vendor separately. So it would be `money` when Sql Server, `numeric(d,p)` when Oracle, etc.

Comment: Hi Gert, you may be right, but that still doesnt make "money" the right choice. And I simply cant recommend DB vendor lock in.